# Empty Swagger specification is created in Go API

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

I am trying to use generate swagger spec from my API handler.

I have installed the go-swagger from `go get`:

```
go get -u github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger
```

See the project structure below:

[image: Go]

`main.go` uses handler definitions in `products.go`. (API works and is tested)

Swagger spec in  `product.go`:

```
// Package classification of Product API.
//
// Documenting for Product API
//
//
//
// Schemes: http, https
// BasePath: /
// Version: 0.0.1
//
// Consumes:
// - application/json
//
// Produces:
// - application/json
//
// swagger:meta
```

Running the following command from `main.go` path:

```
GO111MODULE=off swagger generate spec -o ./swagger.yaml --scan-models
```

Response:

```
info: {}
paths: {}
swagger: "2.0"
```

Expected Response:

```
basePath: /
consumes:
- application/json
info:
  description: Documenting for Product API
  title: 
  version: 0.0.1
paths: {}
producrs:
- application/json
schemes:
- http
swagger: "2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are following Nic's [MSA Go tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07XhTqE-j8k&list=PLmD8u-IFdreyh6EUfevBcbiuCKzFk0EW_&index=8).

In case you haven't figure out the issue yet, you forgot to add a space for the contents. (lines between the first and last line)

Your documentation comment should be as below

```
// Documentation for Product API
//
//  Schemes: http
//  BasePath: /
//  Version: 1.0.0
//
//  Consumes:
//  - application/json
//
//  Produces:
//  - application/json
//
// swagger:meta
```

Answer (score 1):

In adition to @sssang comment. Make sure you leave no space between Documentation comment and the package definition.

```golang
// Documentation for Product API
//
//  Schemes: http
//  BasePath: /
//  Version: 1.0.0
//
//  Consumes:
//  - application/json
//
//  Produces:
//  - application/json
//
// swagger:meta
package handlers

[...rest of your code]
```